# Noetherian local ring is Artinian iff maximal ideal is nilpotent

Tags: commutative-algebra, noetherian

I am browsing through some old lecture notes, and I am trying to prove the following:

> Let $A$ be a Noetherian local ring with maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$. Show that the following are equivalent:
>
> (a) $\mathfrak m^{q}=0$ for some $q\in \mathbb N.$
>
> (b) $A$ is Artinian.

I am only interested in $(a)\implies (b)$. So suppose that $I_0 \supset I_1 \supset \cdots$ is a descending chain of ideals. One is easily able to show that there exists an $n_0$, such that:

$$\dfrac{I_n\cap \mathfrak m^r}{I_n\cap \mathfrak m^{r+1}}=\dfrac{I_{n+1}\cap \mathfrak m^r}{I_{n+1}\cap \mathfrak m^{r+1}}, \forall n\ge n_0,r.$$

Now the proof claims that, the following chain of inclusions holds:

$$I_{n}\subset I_{n+1}+(I_n\cap \mathfrak m)\subset I_{n+1}+(I_n\cap \mathfrak m^2)\subset \cdots \subset I_{n+1}+(I_n\cap \mathfrak m^q)=I_{n+1}\forall n\ge n_0,$$

but I don't understand why this is true and I need some help here.

Comment: Take $r=0$ to get the first inclusion, take $r=1$ to get second etc. For example, with $r=0$, you have $\frac{I_n}{I_n\cap\mathfrak{m}}=\frac{I_{n+1}}{I_{n+1}\cap\mathfrak{m}}$, which translates into the first inclusion.

Answer (score 1):

The equality you mentioned comes from the inclusion $$\frac{I_{n+1}\cap\mathfrak m^r}{I_{n+1}\cap\mathfrak m^{r+1}}\subseteq\frac{I_n\cap\mathfrak m^r}{I_n\cap\mathfrak m^{r+1}},$$ so for $x\in I_n\cap\mathfrak m^r$ there is $y\in I_{n+1}\cap\mathfrak m^r$ such that $x-y\in I_n\cap\mathfrak m^{r+1}$. This shows that $I_n\cap\mathfrak m^r\subseteq I_{n+1}\cap\mathfrak m^r+I_n\cap\mathfrak m^{r+1}$. Now consider $r=0$, then $r=1$, and so on.

**Edit.** In order to give a full proof of $(a)\implies(b)$ let me mention that for each $n,r\ge 0$
$$\frac{I_n\cap\mathfrak m^r}{I_n\cap\mathfrak m^{r+1}}$$ 
is a finitely generated $R/\mathfrak m$-vector space, and therefore there is no such strictly descending chain.

Comment: Is the R/m-vector space in your answer generated by the generators of m (finitely many due to Noetherianness of R)?

Comment: No. It is a quotient of a finitely generated ideal of R.