# In a Noetherian local ring every ideal is a power of the Jacobson radical

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

[image]

> I want to prove that for $R$ a commutative Noetherian local ring, if the Jacobson radical $J$ is nilpotent then $R$ is Artinian.

My question comes from [these lecture notes](https://warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/maths/people/staff/fbouyer/ring_theory.pdf) where the comment in the bracket confuses me. I want to use the fact that in a commutative Noetherian ring, $\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} J^k=0 $ and show that $R,J,J^2,\dots, J^s=0 $ are all the ideals in $R$. But how can I show that every ideal is a power of the Jacobson radical?

Comment: Is this true? If $R=\mathbb C[X,Y]/(X^2,Y^2)$ the maximal ideal is $\mathfrak m=(x,y)$ and the ideal $(x)$ is not a power of $\mathfrak m$.

Comment: This claim comes from a lecture note but now I think it is not true by your example.

Comment: For a proof see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1734834/noetherian-local-ring-is-artinian-iff-maximal-ideal-is-nilpotent).

Answer (score 1):

> But how can I show that every ideal is a power of the Jacobson radical?

You can't, because that would imply the ideals of the ring are linearly ordered, which of course may not be the case.

Here is the [DaRT search](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=1&H=64l&H=21&H=23&L=76l) showing at least two commutative, local, Noetherian, non-uniserial rings.

To make progress on the problem, I suggest taking the chain of powers of the radical and working out that there must be a finite composition series. That would imply the ring is Artinian.

---

Another way to do it, if you know a commutative zero dimensional Noetherian ring is Artinian, is to note that $J$ is a nilpotent maximal ideal, and hence can be the only prime ideal in the entire ring. Consequently, the ring is zero dimensional.

Comment: Could you suggest how to show that it is Artinian?

Comment: @Nicky I went ahead and just moved the suggestion into the solution.